Twillo python not generating audio from stream
I'm trying to generate audio to user using twillo and elevenlabs. When I directly send the conversation when called to "generate audio" then it works and generates the audio.
But the first thing that happens to conversation is that it goes to "Startcall" and then sends microphone stream to a websocket which will transcribe conversation (when sentence has ended) and send it back to python server using Get (@app.get("/transcription")).
then python will make the ai response and then I want it to generate audio. but it is not generating audio or if it goes to "Generateaudio" then it doesn't go audiostream. This only happens when I send user (when called) to "Startcall first".
does anyone know why this is happening. It might be because of the stream for microphone because that's the only thing that is different.
@app.post("/Startcall")
async def incoming_call(request: Request):
    global connection
    try:
        print("start method")
        form_data = await request.form()
        from_number = form_data.get('From')
        print(f"Call received from: {from_number}")

        response = VoiceResponse()
        response.say("Speak now")


         # Assuming you have a WebSocket connection that needs to be closed
        websocket_url = f"wss://ngrok/ws"
        connection = response.connect()
        stream = connection.stream(url=websocket_url)
        
        # Use the ngrok URL here

        return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        

@app.get("/transcription")
async def receive_transcription(transcription: str):
    global connection
    global GREETING_TEXT

    try:
        print(f"Received transcription: {transcription}")

        # Generate AI response
        ai_assistant.generate_ai_response(transcription)



        # Set the AI response as the text to be spoken
        GREETING_TEXT = "AI test speech"

 
          # Create a new TwiML response
        response = VoiceResponse()

        # End the current TwiML execution
        response.hangup()

        # Redirect to generate audio
        response.redirect("/Generateaudio")


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in receive_transcription: {e}")
    
    return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")



@app.post("/Test")
async def test_function():
    try:
        response = VoiceResponse()

        response.say("Welcome to the service.")
        response.redirect("/Generateaudio")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")

    
@app.post("/Generateaudio")
async def genaudio():
    global GREETING_TEXT
    try:


        response = VoiceResponse()

        #ngrok_url = request.headers.get("host")
        ngrok_url = "https://ngrok"

        response.connect().stream(url=f"wss://{ngrok_url.replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '')}/audiostream")

        return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error ", e)


@app.websocket("/audiostream")
async def audiostream(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    global GREETING_TEXT
    try:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.receive_json()
            if message['event'] == 'start':
                stream_sid = message['start']['streamSid']
                
                # Generate audio using ElevenLabs
                audio_stream = elevenlabs.generate(
                    api_key=elevenlabs_api_key,
                    text=GREETING_TEXT,
                    voice=VOICE,
                    model="eleven_multilingual_v2",
                    output_format=OUTPUT_FORMAT,
                    stream=True
                )

                # Stream the audio to Twilio
                for chunk in audio_stream:
                    audio_payload = base64.b64encode(chunk).decode('utf-8')
                    await websocket.send_json({
                        "event": "media",
                        "streamSid": stream_sid,
                        "media": {
                            "payload": audio_payload
                        }
                    })
                    # Add a small delay between chunks
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.12)
                
                # Send some silence to ensure the last word is heard
                silence = b'\x00' * 1600  # 100ms of silence for 8kHz ulaw
                for _ in range(5):  # Send 500ms of silence
                    silence_payload = base64.b64encode(silence).decode('utf-8')
                    await websocket.send_json({
                        "event": "media",
                        "streamSid": stream_sid,
                        "media": {
                            "payload": silence_payload
                        }
                    })
                    #await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

                # End the stream
                await websocket.send_json({
                    "event": "stop",
                    "streamSid": stream_sid
                })
                
                break  # Exit the loop after sending all audio
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"WebSocket error: {e}")
    finally:
        await websocket.close()

I tried using own post request and using redirect and response.hangup(). I was expecting to it successfully send to generate audio and then send it too audiostream.
